# Printing superscripts in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, superscript

I am creating a projectile motion simulator using Tkinter. I have labels in the interface which display different projectile motion equations. One equation I need to display is:

v^2 = u^2+ 2as

I have researched thoroughly and have read that v$^{/2} works but I may not be setting it up correctly and is appears as v2 not v(squared).

How do I print v^2 and ^2 so it appears as v(squared) and u(squared) rather than v2 and u2?

EDIT:
Thank you for your responses but I do not consider this to be a duplicate of the other thread. I can see that it can be done by importing the "sympy" module but is there a way to do it using the standard python library?

Comment: What is the quesion ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can see that it can be done by importing the "sympy" module but is there a way to do it using the standard python library?

Comment: When you say "print", do you mean "print to the console"? Or, are you asking how to insert text with superscripts into a widget?

Comment: Print to the console in the form of the text written on at Tkinter label widget